# Why doesn't this while loop stop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite

> For some reason I cannot get this code to properly sort. I am replacing out of order numbers in order to make an ordered list.

```
 var unsortedArray = new Array(1,2,5,4);

    var sortedArray = unsortedArray;
    var tempValue = 0;

    function isSorted(array)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function sort(array)
    {



        while (isSorted(array) == false)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var tempValue = array[i];

                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = tempValue;
            }
        }
    }

    sort(sortedArray);

    document.write(sortedArray);
```

> The while loop here is supposed to stop when the array is sorted, but that never happens.

Comment: Hypothesis: the array is not sorted as expected.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < length; i++)` Where are you getting `length`, i dont see it defined anywhere so your for loop that is supposed to sort doesnt run, or will use the global `length` property and will use that number instead of whatever you meant it to be

Comment: Your sort is not comparing the elements to see if they need to be swapped. It just always swaps them regardless of whether they need it or not.  So the array is never getting into a sorted state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a endless loop since this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var tempValue = array[i];

        array[i] = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = tempValue;
    }
```

Doesn't sort an array.

Why not use the [array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) instead?

Comment: I'm trying not to use the sort method, I'm trying to make my own way of sorting the numbers.

Comment: You can add a compare function with your own logic like this `arr.sort(function(a,b){ if(a > 12) return a;  return b;});`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

It will swap elements only if `a[n]` is less than `a[n-1]`.

```
while (isSorted(array) == false)
{
    for (i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
    {
      if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
             var tempValue = array[i];
             array[i] = array[i+1];
             array[i+1] = tempValue;
       }
}
```

It also changes the for loop to be `for(var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)`.

Otherwise, at the end of the array, you'll be accessing `array[length]` which will be undefined(Luckily that wouldn't affect the sorting, but it's better to be correct anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var tempValue = array[i];

        array[i] = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = tempValue;
    }
```

here you never check whether  the adjascent values are sorted..... ot the left value is greater than right value....(though i am considering length in the for loop of the sort function to be array length)

Review a simple bubble sort algo and then try.....

refer this algo in C [here](http://www.programiz.com/algorithm/bubble-sort)